# Nginx in a subdirectory

Tags: nginx, redhat

I have some websites that some are in php and others in nodejs
however all will be sub folders of **misrv177** domain

my configuration is as follows

**default**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/;
        server_name misrv177;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

}
```

**frontend**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root  /var/www/html/gemeos-frontend/dist;
        server_name misrv177;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/gemeos-frontend-access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/gemeos-frontend-error.log;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
        location ^~/gemeos {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

}
```

**backend**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/public;
        server_name misrv177;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/gemeos-backend-access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/gemeos-backend-error.log;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }



}
```

When I try to access eg **misrv177/gemeos** it returns a 404 error

Comment: `server_name misrv177 ;` should be something like `server_name misrv177 .com;` and should be different per folder. Use subdomains

Comment: This domain will only be used on the internal network, so it is without .com

Comment: Nginx can serve only one (precisely first) server block if you used the same `server_name` in multiple places, discarding other server blocks. Your setup probably wants alias directive... https://nginx.org/r/alias

Comment: You should probably read [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)